# Provide Dagger flavor-specific module

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, android-productflavors

I have an application with 5 flavours. I just want one of them to provide a different dagger module implementation (which the same interface). I don't want to create this module in each flavor, I just want to have a flavor-specific module and a default one for all other flavors. So I've tried to use the directory `main` to keep the default module, while implementing a different one in one of the flavors. Of course, this does not work as a redeclaration error is thrown.

Is there a way to achieve an aproach like this, to create a default dagger module for all flavors, but an alternative implementation just for one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 options to achieve this:

1. Add source set specific modules (`src/flavorA/java`, `src/flavorB/java`) for all product flavors and don’t define the module in main source set (as that will throw an error due to redeclaration)
2. You can add the dagger module in the `main source set` and have an `if else` check on the constant for product flavour in the `BuildConfig` class to provide the relevant implementation for your interface.

PS: Product flavors in Gradle work by merging the source code for the main and the flavor specific source set hence any class in flavor specific source sets needs to be defined specifically for all flavor source sets and never in main to avoid a compilation error.

Resources are also merged similarly but in case of a clash between main and flavor source set the latter overrides without any errors

Comment: Hi @rahul.taicho, I don't want to introduce logic to pick an implementation, I just want to be able to provide the right implementation from the module itself

Comment: I’ve expanded my answer, please let me know if the options are unclear

Comment: I was thinking somethink like have a "common" source set folder, so that the default implementation goes there. Then, I add that folder to the rest of flavors, except for the last one, which has a different implementation. That way, I don't have to repeat the same implementation in every flavor.

Comment: That is doable but misleading because `common` implies it'll be shared across flavors, also it solves your current issue by adjusting build scripts but may not scale very well suppose you have a different use-case later where you need to provision implementations differently.

TL;DR If you're working with a team you should avoid it, working on a solo project you'd have little confusion so it could still work out. (long term you might still view it as a technical debt though)